# With Google AdSense JavaScript pages are loading twice

Tags: javascript, adsense

When I place Adsense ads on my website pages are loading twice. When I remove Adsense everything works normal. I generated new async code for my Adsense ads but it still works wrong. The ads are shown in the right way. But - possibly due to the Mediapartners-crawler van Google - the pages are loading twice.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this?

Comment: How are you tracking it loading twice?

Comment: The Adsense ads are placed on a website for desktop-browsing. The actions (like database-transactions and mails generated by the php-scripts) are performed twice with Adsense adds and performed only once after removing the ads.